# How to create a half transparent window in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

[Here green part of images indicating the transparent part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkdPO.png)

Now I want to create a same type of window in tkinter. The main window is divided into two vertical boxes. Right box is fully transparent and left box have some tkinter widgets. The main problem is I'm unable to make a half transparent window in tkinte..

Comment: For Windows platform, use `root.atttributes("-transparentcolor", "green")` to make parts with green color transparent.